# What specific fitting do I need to connect a 1/4" copper refrigerator water tube to a 3/4" steel water line that's already in use?

Tags: plumbing, water, refrigerator, interior

I recently bought a new refrigerator (Samsung RF263BEAESR) and am trying to connect it to my house's water supply line (under the kitchen sink).  The prior owner of the house ran a copper line from the sink area to the general location of the fridge but neither end was hooked up and our prior refrigerator didn't have an ice maker.

I carefully reviewed the instruction manual for the new fridge but Samsung only provides instructions for applying a saddle valve on copper pipes. This won't work because my house has steel pipes that aren't easily accessible (besides, I'm not a fan of saddle valves to beginwith).

Here's a picture of the current water supply valves under the kitchen sink:

[image: WaterSupplyValve]

I'm hoping that I could replace this valve with something that will support a single 3/4" threaded steel input and have multiple outlets (one going to the sink faucet -- threaded 1/2" I think -- and another going to the copper compression fitting).  Do this approach make these?  Is this a bad idea? Does the refrigerator line need to be on a completely separate connection to the house water?

Comment: I think kitchen sinks are 3/8" (but I can never remember). So you'll want a 3/8" female, 1/4" male, 3/8" male tee. You should be able to find one at the local big box,  or hardware store.

Answer (score 2):

I think kitchen sinks are 3/8" (but I can never remember). So you'll want a 3/8" female, 1/4" male, 3/8" male tee. You should be able to find one at the local big box, or hardware store.

Something [like this](http://m.homedepot.com/p/Homewerks-Worldwide-3-8-in-x-3-8-in-x-1-4-in-Brass-Extender-Tee-No-Lead-VETOEMB1B-Z/203444232)

[image]

1. Shut off the water using the shutoff valve.
2. Remove the existing supply line.
3. Attach the tee where the supply line used to be.
4. Connect the sink supply to the 3/8" male outlet on the tee.
5. Connect the refrigerator supply to the 1/4" outlet on the tee.

***NOTE:*** Use your preferred pipe dope method (tape or goop), however, since it's a brass fitting dope should not be required.

Comment: So essentially a tee fitting and then two separate valves connected to that? One valve going to the sink faucet and one compression valve going to the refrigerator supply?

Comment: Yup the image and link will give you exactly what need

Comment: @MikeB No. The tee comes after the valve.  One valve for both, or you could install two more valves if you'd like.

Comment: I installed the connection for my refrigerator using almost the exact same type of adapter Tee as shown by @Tester101. The difference in my case was that the 1/4" side was a female thread to which I installed a small shutoff valve and then continued on to another Tee off to the refrigerator and a separate water filter unit. Having the shutoff for the 1/4" lines means you can turn off the ice-maker supply when you have to move you refrigerator for cleaning without losing cold water at your sink.

Comment: I found the following while perusing at home depot: http://www.homedepot.com/p/BrassCraft-1-2-in-FIP-Inlet-x-1-2-in-OD-Comp-x-1-4-in-OD-Comp-Outlet-Rough-Brass-Multi-Turn-Dual-Outlet-Valve-No-Lead-R3700RX-R1/202047032  Would something like this work? Both output connections appear designed for compression threads so I wonder if the connection to the sink would have issues?

Comment: That would work, if the sink hose is 1/2".

Comment: [Déjà vu](http://diy.stackexchange.com/a/25161/33)